# Maven Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, ubuntu-14.04

New to maven and ubuntu. Maven version is 3.0.5. First i imported a maven project into eclipse and there were lot of maven dependency error. So i did maven clean install from pom.xml location using terminal and subsequent mvn install command from terminal build was successful. But if I import the project again and update project into eclipse I see 5 errors.

Maven configuration Problem:

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:pom:2.2 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:pom:2.2 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connect timed out  pom.xml /loga line"

Maven Problem

> Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   CoreException: Could not get the value for parameter compilerId for plugin execution default-compile: PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.2.1, org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.2.1, org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:2.2.1, org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.2.1, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-parameter-documenter:jar:2.2.1, org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.2.1, org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.2.1, org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.2.1, org.apache.maven:maven-error-diagnostics:jar:2.2.1, org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.2.1, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.2.1, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-descriptor:jar:2.2.1, org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.2.1, org.apache.maven:maven-monitor:jar:2.2.1, org.apache.maven:maven-toolchain:jar:2.2.1, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.5.5, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-classworlds:jar:2.2.2: Failure to transfer org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.2.1 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.2.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect timed out   pom.xml /loga   line 334    Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem
>
> Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   CoreException: Could not get the value for parameter compilerId for plugin execution default-testCompile: PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.2.1, org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.2.1, org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:2.2.1, org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.2.1, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-parameter-documenter:jar:2.2.1, org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.2.1, org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.2.1, org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.2.1, org.apache.maven:maven-error-diagnostics:jar:2.2.1, org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.2.1, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.2.1, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-descriptor:jar:2.2.1, org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.2.1, org.apache.maven:maven-monitor:jar:2.2.1, org.apache.maven:maven-toolchain:jar:2.2.1, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.5.5, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-classworlds:jar:2.2.2: Failure to transfer org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.2.1 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.2.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect timed out   pom.xml /loga   line 334    Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem
>
> Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (execution: default-compile, phase: compile)    pom.xml /loga   line 334    Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem
>
> Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:testCompile (execution: default-testCompile, phase: test-compile)   pom.xml /loga   line 334    Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem

And if try to update maven project I get an error alert

> Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:jar:2.2
>   Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:jar:2.2

Same project I imported in windows environment and there were no errors Where as in ubuntu i see above errors. I have spent 10 hours googling with out any solution. Any help appreciated.

Comment: try to delete your local repositiory and run maven again

Comment: you mean delete everything under .m2 folder? and which command should I run ? From eclipse or from terminal?

Comment: Yes i mean deleting the .m2 folder. After that you can run "Update Project" from eclipse or any mvn command on command line.

Comment: @Jens after deleting repository folder and updating project from eclipse errors have raised to 70 dependency problem. 1 maven configuration problem and 1 maven problem

Comment: And the error Messages are?

Comment: configuration problem is > "Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:jar:2.2
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:jar:2.2"

Comment: maven problem is "Description Resource Path Location Type
Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:pom:2.2 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:pom:2.2 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connect timed out pom.xml /loga line 1 Maven Configuration Problem"

Comment: dependency problem has : 70 failed to read artifacts of some jar

Comment: I did mvn clean install. now i have 5 errors as described above

Comment: did you check if eclipse uses the correct proxy? (I mean, if you are using a proxy at all)

Comment: what do u mean by proxy? really sorry am new to maven

Comment: In case some one faces same issue. Please check if your eclipse can connect to market place. If not add proxy . To check your proxy host please use set | grep -i proxy if ubuntu